# Is this a valid solution to a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. $$(y+1)^2\frac{dy}{dx}=-x^3$$
   So by expanding RHS, multiplying by dx and integrating we have:

$$\int y^2+2y+1 dy=-\int x^3 dx$$
 then by integrating factoring out a $y$ on the LHS and dividing by the bracket we have $$y(x,y)=\frac{-\frac{1}{4}x^4+c}{(\frac{1}{3}y^2+y+1)}$$

Is this even right? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can do $\int (y+1)^2 \, dy = \frac 13 (1+y)^3 $ too. imagine what you would have to do if it were $\int (1+ y) ^{10 \, dy.$

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly right. Your first step, separating the equations, is correct, but your final algebra isn't. After integrating, you get an algebraic equation: $\frac{y^3}{3} + y^2 + y = -\frac{x^4}{4}+c$. Your result that $y = \frac{-\frac{1}{4}x^4+c}{(\frac{1}{3}y^2+y+1)}$ is true, but this isn't a solution. The fact that you had to write $y(x,y)$ reveals this -- how can $y$ be a function of itself?

Comment: Okay I see this but I thought some solutions had to be in terms of themselves? So what should I do I can't see what to do differently? Thanks

Comment: Chinny84's answer is correct. Solutions can't be in terms of themselves; think of a simple equation x = 2x+1. x is given in terms of itself here, and that's why we haven't solved the equation

Answer (score 1):

Firstly tip, put the solution back in to see. But to be honest the form is not the nicest.

you could do this $y +1 = v$

$$
v^2\frac{dv}{dx} =-x^3
$$thus we have
$$
\frac{v^3}{3} = -\frac{x^4}{4} + c
$$
There fore we could write as
$$
v =\left( C_1-\frac{3}{4}x^4\right)^{1/3}
$$
Or
$$
y = \left( C_1-\frac{3}{4}x^4\right)^{1/3}-1
$$

Comment: I didn't spot the change of variable. This is a very nice solution.

Comment: Would be answer be incorrect then if I wrote it how I did at the start? Would a change of variable always be the way to go here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can rearrange your solution with an appropiate adjustment of the constant you use (namely to get the 1) to factorise your cubic. I would say yes for this problem, but I am biased as I always try to simplify or normalise equations since the family of solutions will be the same up to a scaling factor. However, at this level I think you did great, experience will make these manipulations and transformations jump out :). Keep it up.